# Как правильно произносить?

Tags: орфоэпия, фонология

Как правильно произносить слова СКУЧНО, СКВОРЕЧНИК, ПРАЧЕЧНАЯ со звуком  «Ч»  или  «Ш»? Мне кажется, что в Московской фонологической школе «ш», а в Ленинградской — «ч». Скорее всего, допускаются два варианта. Так как же всё–таки правильно? И какая наблюдается тенденция в русском языке?

Comment: В Петербурге говорят "ску-ч-но", но "скворе-ш-ник" и "прачешная". Более явное отличие: никогда не говорят "дожжи" и "дощщ" (только "дошть" и "дожди"), как это можно услышать даже в московских фильмах о Петербурге - не говоря о дикторах Центрального ТВ и московских поп-певцах.

Comment: Да, наши дикторы, как Вы правильно заметили, - это отдельная "песня".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в нашем языке идет постоянная борьба традиционного произношения и произношения написанного. Чем грамотнее нация, тем больше люди склоняются к написанному. Влияет и то, откуда человек узнал слово. Приведу примеры:

1. Мои бабушка и мать всегда стирали дома, и слово "прачечная" я прочел в книге.
2. Всем детям в нашем городе (и мне) говорили: "Сбегай в хлебный". Вопрос: как я буду произносить слова "прачечная" и "булочная", если меня не переучивать в угоду далёким мне питерским (московским) традициям? Кстати, сквореШник висел у меня прямо перед окном.

Теперь о словарях. Наиболее уважающие себя авторы отражают в них реальное состояние языка как результат серьёзных исследований. Некоторые — результат перепечатывания старых источников. В этом смысле у меня вызывают недоверие некоторые современные издания. В итоге, на мой взгляд, здесь не следует ставить вопрос о "правильности" произношения, скорее это вопрос "традиционности для какой-либо местности".

Comment: Абсолютно с Вами согласна, Андрей. Наверное, надо говорить не о тенденции, а о сложившейся в той или иной местности традиции. Очень верно подмечено, спасибо.

Comment: Не за что! Всегда приятно общаться с умными неравнодушными людьми :-)

Answer (score 1):

Обратимся к словарям:

1. *Орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Н. А. Еськова. АСТ, 2015.* Скучный [шн], скворечник [шнь], прачечная [шн].
2. *Большой орфоэпический словарь. М. Л. Каленчук. АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2016.* Скучно [ш] ([ч'] не рек.), скворечник [ш], прачечная [ш] и *допуст. младш.* [ч'].
3. *Словарь трудностей русского языка для работников СМИ. М. А. Штудинер. Словари XXI века, 2016.* Скучный [шн], скворечник [шн], прачечная [шн].

Таким образом, современные орфоэпические словари рекомендуют во всех случаях произношение [шн].
В некоторых книгах, статьях встречаются указания на вариативность [чн] и [шн], однако, как видно, в настоящее время лексикографически она практически не фиксируются.

Фонологические школы не про это, как говорится.

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ Грамоты.ру Вопрос № 280260](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=280260)

Таким образом, существуют три варианта: только ЧН, только ШН, ЧН и ШН.

Кстати, фонологические школы вроде бы занимаются именно фонологией (определяют, что такое фонема и т.д.), а не произношением, так что скорее можно говорит о разных традициях произношения в Москве и Петербурге.

Comment: Спасибо,Sibilla. Но звук в функциональном аспекте - это собственно и есть фонема, а она может быть как в сильной, так и в слабой позиции. Не так?

Comment: А это какая у Вас школа? Согласно Московской школе, фонема - это смыслоразличительный звук в СИЛЬНОЙ позиции (буквенная запись слова соответствует его фонемной записи).  Но в нашем случае позиция фонемы Ч неясна - фонетическое чередование Ч/Ш перед Н происходит, но оно  нерегулярно, поэтому сложно говорить о слабой или сильной позиции Ч.

Comment: Понятно, что говорить здесь о "школе" не стоит, я имела в виду функционирование звука. Не придирайтесь к словам, Сибилла. Помягче, ещё мягче!

Comment: Фонемы и фонологические школы - это вещь в себе.  Казалось бы очень важное открытие фонемы практической пользы принесло немного, а в настоящий момент и того хуже:  понимание фонетических процессов зашло в совершенный тупик (но это исключительно мое личное мнение).  И ещё: пользуясь случаем,  хочу сказать  участникам форума, что испытываю к ним самые искренние и дружелюбные чувства даже в тех случаях, когда мы не всегда понимаем друг друга.

Comment: Согласна, давайте дружить домами